# Creating Flash application using WebOrb Ruby/Rails

Tags: apache-flex, flash, weborb, remoteobject

Ok, this may seem like a stupid question (for Flash Developers) but I really can't figure this out.
So, I want to create somekind of an API for Flash/Flex applications so a user can use my lib in order to connect to my WebOrb Rails server.

I don't have any problem with the rails part but things get a little bit difficult with the flash part.

So, I saw from the example that Flex is using the RemoteObject to connect/retrieve data.
The question is how can I create a Flash file that connects/retrieves data from WebOrb (i couldn't find the RemoteObject - is an include I should make?).

If that is not possible, can I create some sort of library in Flex, that can be linked in Flash in order to achieve the same result?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is most likely the `NetConnection` Actionscript class. Depends on the format of your API though. If it's just XML over HTTP, you could easily just use the `URLLoader` class as well.

NetConnection
[link text](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetConnection.html)

URLLoader
[link text](http://tush.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/actionscript-3-using-urlloader-to-send-and-load-server-variables/)